# For $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$, $\Re(s)>0$, evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\left(2\pi ne^{x}\right)\left[\frac{s}{e^{sx}-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right]dx$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and $s\in \mathbb{C}\;,\Re(s)>0$. I want to compute the integral :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\left(2\pi ne^{x}\right)\left[\frac{s}{e^{sx}-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right]dx$$

I tried using the integral presentation found [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sin/07/02/) :

$$\sin(2\pi ne^{x})=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\pi i }\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(z)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}-z \right )}\left(\pi n \right )^{-2z+1}e^{-(2z-1)x}dz\;\;\;\;\;0<\gamma<1$$
in conjunction with :
$$r+\log(r)+\psi\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)=-\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y}\left(\frac{r}{e^{ry}-1}-\frac{1}{y}\right)dy$$
Where $\psi\left(\cdot\right)$ is the digamma function. But that made the problem even more difficult. Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT** :

Using the Fourier reciprocity :
$$\frac{s}{e^{sx}-1}-\frac{1}{x}=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e^{2\pi \theta/s}-1}-\frac{s}{2\pi \theta} \right )\sin(x\theta)d\theta$$
Our integral reads :
$$2\int_{0}^{\infty} g(\theta)\left(\frac{1}{e^{2\pi \theta/s}-1}-\frac{s}{2\pi \theta} \right )d\theta$$
Where :
$$g(\theta)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(2\pi ne^{x})\sin(x\theta)dx$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\pi i }\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(z)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}-z \right )}\left(\pi n \right )^{-2z+1}\frac{\theta}{\theta^{2}+(2z-1)^{2}}dz$$

Comment: You meant $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sin\left(2\pi ne^{x}\right)\left[\frac{s}{e^{sx}-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right]dx$

Comment: $\int_0^\infty\sin\left(2\pi ne^{x}\right)\left[\frac{s}{e^{sx}-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right]dx$ is the incomplete version of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sin\left(2\pi ne^{x}\right)\left[\frac{s}{e^{sx}-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right]dx$ which has way more chances to be evaluated, why do you need the former

Comment: What context did this come up in? This seems like a very esoteric problem.

Comment: It is esoteric indeed. This integral came up in the study of a certain number-theoretic function. The function between the parentheses is self reciprocal wrt the Fourier sine transform, and can be used to prove the transformation formula of the Dedekind eta function, when the sine factor is $\sin(2\pi n x)$. The problem above is a little bit different, but concerns a closely related function.

Comment: Did you consider numeric approximation (for fixed values of $s,n$) to get an idea? If you evaluate the integral from $0$ to some $n$ this integral should be well approximated even for relatively small $n$ because for large $x$ the sin term will just average out to zero.

Comment: A quick and dirty conjectural result found using Mathematica and tested for a few values of $n$ and real $s$ is $$I=\frac{1}{2} \pi  \left(\coth \left(\frac{2 \pi ^2 n}{s}\right)-1\right)-\frac{s}{4 \pi  n}$$

Comment: Are you sure you evaluated the integral with $\sin(2\pi n e^{x})$ not $\sin(2\pi nx)$ ?

Comment: Yes your right Sorry

Comment: Are you interested in any sort of asymptotics of $s$? Or do you need an exact closed form?

Comment: I am interested in an exact from

Comment: Using change of variable $y=e^x$ plus noting that $\left[\frac{s}{e^{s x}-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right]=\left[\frac{s \coth \left(\frac{s x}{2}\right)}{2}-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{s}{2}\right]$ I think your integral can be written as $$I=\int_1^{\infty } \frac{\sin (2 \pi  n y)}{y} \left(\frac{s \coth \left(\frac{1}{2} s \log (y)\right)}{2 }-\frac{1}{ \log (y)}-\frac{s}{2 }\right) \, dy$$ The integral  of the $-\frac{s}{2}$ term involving just the sine integral is the largest or principal term. When integrated the term is $\left[ -\frac{1}{2} s \left(\frac{\pi }{2}-\text{Si}(2 n \pi )\right) \right]$.